# Find longest range of free ids in mysql, using a query?

Tags: mysql

This can certainly be done using a simple script and reading the database.
I am interested to know if the same is possible using some MySQL query.

Table Schema :

```
+--------+-------------------------------+
| doc_id | doc_title                     |
+--------+-------------------------------+
| 40692  | hello                         |
| 13873  | isaac                         |
| 37739  | einstei                       |
| 36042  | cricket                       |
| 96249  | astronaut                     |
| 81931  | discovery                     |
| 28447  | scooby                        |
| 99632  | popeye                        |
+--------+-------------------------------+
```

Here doc_id is a random number between 1 to 99999 , the distribution is sparse. I would want to know longest ( or all of the longest ) unused number ranges in my mysql table.
i.e. if 71000 to 83000 is the longest such range, there will be no record having doc_id lying between these two values.

Comment: Would temp table with doc_id and previous_doc_id fit the requirement ?

Comment: @dystroy I would love to see that solution as well.

Comment: My proposal would simply be to fill a temp table by filling previous_id as select max(doc_id) from doc d2 where d2.doc_id<doc_id. The idea would simply to avoid the massive max(d2.doc_id-d1.doc_id) on a join on two ordered table that you can trivially make but would probably take age on a big table (I've not tested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this

```
SELECT t1.doc_id,
       MAX(t1.doc_id-IFNULL(t2.doc_id,0)) AS difference
FROM `table` t1
    LEFT JOIN `table` t2 ON t1.doc_id>t2.doc_id
    LEFT JOIN `table` t3 ON (t1.doc_id>t3.doc_id AND t3.doc_id>t2.doc_id)
WHERE t3.doc_id IS NULL
GROUP BY t1.doc
ORDER BY difference DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
create table documents ( id int, name varchar(255) );

insert into documents (id, name ) values

( 40692,'hello'),
( 13873,'isaac'),
( 37739,'einstei'),
( 36042,'cricket'),
( 96249,'astronaut'),
( 81931,'discovery'),
( 28447,'scooby'),
( 99632,'popeye')

select
    d1.id,
    min( d2.id ),
    min( d2.id ) - d1.id as 'gap'
from
    documents d1
    join documents d2 on d2.id > d1.id
group by
    d1.id
order by
    3 desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query -

```
SELECT start_doc_id, doc_id end_doc_id, delta FROM (
  SELECT
    doc_id,
    @d start_doc_id,
    IF(@d IS NULL, 0, doc_id - @d) delta,
    @d:=doc_id
  FROM
    doc, (SELECT @d:= NULL) t
    ORDER BY doc_id
  ) doc
ORDER BY delta DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd look for a different solution from Wolfgang's if your documents table gets big (hundreds of thousands or millions of records) because a join with "on d2.id > d1.id" is going to create a *huge* temporary table and take lots of time.

If *you* create the temporary table, you can do it quickly:

```
create table tdoc (id int, nextid int);
insert into tdoc (id) (select id from documents);
update tdoc join documents as d1 
  on d1.id = tdoc.id
  set nextid = 
    (select id from documents 
    where id > tdoc.id order by id limit 1);
select id, max(nextid-id) from tdoc;
```

There's no self-join and no heavy crunching; this solution scales to a large documents table if necessary